# Ayuda con logica de URL

Tags: php, mvc, web

Hola amigos desarrolladores quiero saber cual es la lógica que se sigue en esta url:

https://www.domain.com/historia-tecnologica/la-mayoria-de-paises-del-mundo-no-cambian-la-hora-porque-no-tiene-sentido-hacerlo

Porque no veo ningún identificador para que llame a ese articulo o es como lo estoy pensando, que esta parte es el identificador:

"la-mayoria-de-paises-del-mundo-no-cambian-la-hora-porque-no-tiene-sentido-hacerlo"

Gracias de antemano.

Comment: Te recomiendo que hagas el [tour] y [help] para hacerla pregunta

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Entiendo que la duda es: *¿porque no hay ninguna id en la url?* *¿como se hace eso?* Entendiendo que la pregunta es esa, respondo:

La url no esta compuesta por ninguna ID por temas de SEO y de seguridad. Un buscador valora mucho más si la url es legible por un humano y contiene palabras clave. El tema de seguridad es porque al no poner ninguna id puedes evitar que se realicen muchos tipos de inyecciones sql o que se adivine una secuencia...

Para hacer eso lo que haces es cuando el servidor recibe una petición de la página busca el articulo en la base de dato a través del titulo en vez de por la id.

La lógica que sigue esa url parece ser que es (categoría)/(titulo_articulo)

Answer (score 0):

Este tipo de semántica se le llama  **URL Slug**,  aparece con el auge de los manejadores de contenidos como Wordpress y exigencias de SEO ademas de tener como objetivo principal convertir las URLs mas "user-friendly" y legibles por el humano a simple vista. También se le conoce como "Clean Url".

El estándar original de una URL Slug es: Dominio/ategoria/Keywords

Ejemplo: *http:www.example.org/category/gastronomia-dominicana*

Realmente hay interminables algoritmos para generar URL Slug, sin importar el lenguaje o plataforma e Inclusive uno mismo con ingenio puedo crear el propio. Pero tener en cuenta que Existen varios algoritmos potenciales para normalizar una cadena cuando usas un slug de URL. 
Un patrón típico sería:

- Minúscula la cadena
- Elimine caracteres especiales y puntuación que requieran codificación
  en la URL
- Reemplazar los espacios con un guión.